# Is there a way to access cookie headers for a Wai Web App?

Tags: haskell, cookies, http-headers, servant, haskell-wai

I have a Servant web application. I need to access the cookie headers for debugging purposes. From the browser, I can access the headers including the cookie headers. From the server, I use Wai's RequestLogger to log requests. The results do not show the cookie headers, however.

Is there a way to access the cookie headers in a Wai application?

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.2/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Response

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am taking a look at the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a custom Wai Middleware to log the cookie headers in the requests. Wai Middleware is `Application -> Application`. The details are presented below in case someone finds it useful.

```
logRequestHeaders :: Application -> Application
logRequestHeaders incoming request outgoing = do
   let headerList = requestHeaders request
   liftIO $ mapM_ print headerList
   incoming request outgoing
```